# Selling a MacBook Pro with preinstalled OSX and transferring the license

Tags: macos, apple-id, internet-recovery

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2010 and have since upgraded all the way to Mavericks. I am now selling the device and the online restore option requests my apple ID. Using that, I've installed a clean Mavericks for the buyer.

I think this is the nicest thing for the buyer, but I'm not sure what the consequences are, so I'd have a couple of questions for you guys:

- With the system I've updated, will the buyer be asked for his apple ID and will that replace mine?
- If that's not the case, will he be able to do updates without having the password to my account?
- Can I change the Apple ID that owns mavericks to him, even if I have to gift him Mavericks?
- Is there a better way to do all this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- With the system I've updated, will the buyer be asked for his apple ID and will that replace mine?

When they first use the system and create a User ID etc, they will be asked for an Apple ID (which is not entirely mandatory) and it will have no knowledge of you as the previous owner, nor will it care what ID is used.

- If that's not the case, will he be able to do updates without having the password to my account?

Updates will be possible without having any knowledge of the ID that originally purchased it

- Can I change the Apple ID that owns mavericks to him, even if I have to gift him Mavericks?

No, purchases via the Mac App Store are tied to your ID, and cannot be transferred.  Also, you cannot gift a free app.

- Is there a better way to do all this?

Not really, you should just advise the purchaser to "buy" (It's free, so no cost) a copy of Mavericks against his own ID, such that it can be used for restores etc in future and to ensure that he owns a copy legitimately.  He should be able to purchase it on a machine that is already running it, simply by logging into the App store with an ID that has not already purchased it.  It may kick off a pointless download which can be cancelled, but it will get him square from a licensing terms perspective, and from a safety/recoverability perspective.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for spelling it out so clearly, the information out there is really mixed! That's great then, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say first restore it and then sell it. You dont need to give you apple id. Also for updates, you don't need Apple id. If nobody buy it, I know a website that buy these MacBooks. I sold mine with damaged logic board for $220. You could try it. Here is the site address 
http://www.computerstar.ca/sell-macbook-macbookpro-toronto-mississauga.html

I hope this helps. Thank you and good luck.